# Asus N55SF build-in screen not working after Windows update

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, display

Today Windows 8 (genuine version) performed a Windows update. At the time my laptop was plugged into an external Samsung TV via HDMI. After the installation of the update it asked me to reboot the laptop, which I did.

Ever since that moment the build-in display of the laptop has been blank. It does turn on (I can see that the back-light goes on), but nothing appears on the screen. On the external Samsung TV Windows was showing, so the first thing I did was uninstall the latest updates that Windows 8 had installed. This did not fix the problem.

Then I re-installed the drivers of the on-board Intel video-card. This did not fix the problem either.

Then I removed the motherboard battery, rebooted the laptop, put the battery back, reboot the laptop again, to reset the BIOS. This did not fix the problem either.

Then I went back to Windows 8 (on the Samsung TV via HDMI), and I re-installed the drivers of the Nvidia graphics card that is also build into the laptop. During this process, the Samsung TV screen went black, and did not come back anymore after. I restarted the computer, but now I also cannot get the external display to work anymore via HDMI.

As a result now, I have a build-in display which shows nothing, and an external display which does not work, so basically a totally unusable laptop.

Just to be clear, the build-in display also shows nothing during the boot-up process, so I cannot get into the BIOS to do anything, nor format and re-install Windows.

Does anyone have any idea what I could try to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the hardware toggle (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> on your keyboard) to cycle between internal/external/both monitors?

Other ones to check:

- Ensure the backlight isn't turned off: Hit <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to toggle.
- Ensure the notebook's screen brightness is turned up: Repeatedly tap <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to turn up.

More shortcuts: [Function key reference for Asus N55SF](http://www.itreset.com/2011/12/asus-n55sf-function-key-combinations.html)

*Edit*:

If it's not displaying the BIOS (especially after successfully flashing it), and none of the built-in switches affect it.  Then I'd say it's time to take it in for service (or bust out the screw drivers, if your so inclined).

Comment: The backlight is on, and the brightness has been set on maximum. Pressing Fn+F8 does not work at the moment (before the issue started, it did). So I'm still stuck with a laptop that displays nothing :(

Comment: Managed to get the external display working via an old VGA cable. Just flashed the BIOS, and reset to factory defaults, but the build-in display still shows nothing. I can tell that it's on though, by the backlight being on. Any idea?

Comment: @Mr.Boon See my edit :)

Comment: THe built-in switches do affect it, i can see that the brightness goes up/down, backlight goes on/off, but it's simply not showing anything on the screen. BIOS has been flashed, also reset by taking out the motherboard battery. I already opened the laptop a while ago to install a different keyboard, so I have no warrenty from Asus anymore :(

Comment: Still no solution :(